# コマンドライン引数がこちらの辞書型のキーになる理由を教えてください。

Tags: python, python3

こんにちは。Python初心者です。

Pythonの教材を勉強していて分からない分野に直面しました。
アル・スウェイガート著の『退屈なことはPythonにやらせよう ―ノンプログラマーにもできる自動化処理プログラミング 』のP146にあるコードからです。

下記のコードの13行目のaccount = sys.argv[1]のことで質問があります。
16行目のコードであるpyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
を読む限り、辞書PASSWORDSのキーにコマンドライン引数が代入されたaccountが
指定されています。

試しに、args[0]が具体的にどのようなものかを調べてみると、このように
出力されます。

```
print(args[1])
```

出力結果

```
C:/Users/PycharmProjects/sampleproject2/pw.py
```

このように、現在のスクリプトのディレクトリが出力されます。
そして、疑問になりこちらで質問させていただきます。

**現在のディレクトリをaccountに代入して、そして、辞書PASSWORDS

のキーに使う理由を教えてください。**

実際のコードはこちらです。

```
PASSWORDS = {'email': 'f;ajljgodjdasofjd',
             'blog': 'jdfjaksdasdkasasdd',
             'luggage': '12345'
}

import sys
import pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('使い方: python pw.py[アカウント名]')
    print('パスワードをクリップボードにコピーします')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print(account + 'のパスワードをクリップボードにコピーしました')
else:
    print(account + 'というアカウント名はありません')
```

Comment: [automatestuff-ja/pw.py](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/automatestuff-ja/blob/master/ch06/pw.py#L16) を見ますと、`account = sys.argv[1]` となっていますね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。質問文のコードの１３行目をaccount = sys.argv[1] に直します。

Comment: コメントと回答で気付いたかもしれませんが、プログラムは質問に太字で書かれたようには動作していない、ということです。プログラムの動作を誤解しているので質問には答え(xxしている理由)が無いでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
account = sys.argv[0]
```

ではなくて、

```
account = sys.argv[1]
```

ではないでしょうか。

```
python pw.py [アカウント名]
```

として Python スクリプト名に続けて「スペースを挟んで」アカウント名をコマンドオプションとして与えて実行すれば、それが `sys.argv[1]` として拾われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃっていることはコマンドプロンプトでの処理でしょうか？

Comment: @taisei `python pw.py [アカウント名]` の部分はコマンドプロンプトで実行することになると思います。

Answer (score 0):

> 現在のディレクトリをaccountに代入して、そして、辞書PASSWORDS
>   のキーに使う理由を教えてください。

`account = sys.argv[0]`は、「現在のディレクトリ」というよりも、実行するスクリプトファイルのパス名ですね。

別ののユーザが実行したり、異なるプロジェクトで実行する場合、`sys.argv[0]`の内容が変わりますので、ユーザまたはプロジェクト毎にパスワードを管理するために、辞書PASSWORDSのキーに`sys.argv[0]`を指定しているのだと思います。

---

【追記】

以上の回答は見当違いな回答でした。

辞書PASSWORDSは単なる例でと思いました。別の方のコメントでわかりましたが「アカウント」は第一引数で渡すのですね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。辞書PASSWORDSのキーには、それぞれ、「email、blog、luggage」とありますが、それらとスクリプトファイルのパス名がどのように関係があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 辞書PASSWORDSは単なる例でと思いました。別の方のコメントでわかりましたが「アカウント」は第一引数で渡すのですね。